# Sub subdomain overridden by subdomain in NGINX

Tags: nginx, subdomain, overriding

I have a server with Nginx.
I would like to set up two sites:

- backend.mysite.com
- staging.backend.mysite.com

Here is my server blocks config:

www.backend.mysite.com:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name backend.mysite.com www.backend.mysite.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8800/; 
        }
}

server {
    listen 8800;
    server_name my.ip.address;
    root /projects/backend/production/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }        
}
```

www.staging.backend.mysite.com:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name staging.backend.mysite.com www.staging.backend.mysite.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8900/; 
        }
}

server {
    listen 8900;
    server_name my.ip.address;
    root /projects/backend/staging/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }        
}
```

My problem is that backend.mysite.com is overriding staging.backend.mysite.com. How can I say to Nginx to never override if there is a sub subdomain on my adress?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to add another domain (my_other_site.com) in my second config to check if it works:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name my_other_site.com www.my_other_site.com staging.backend.mysite.com www.staging.backend.mysite.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8900/; 
        }
}

server {
    listen 8900;
    server_name my.ip.address;
    root /projects/backend/staging/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }        
}
```

When I visit my_other_site.com it works well. The second site is reached as expected.
`my_other_site.com`, `www.my_other_site.com`, `staging.backend.mysite.com` and `www.staging.backend.mysite.com` have the same `DNS A` configuration, they are pointing on the same IP.

**UPDATE 2:**

When I disable `www.backend.mysite.com` server block, it works. The site `staging.backend.mysite.com` is working as expected. That mean that indeed the first block overrides the second one.
How can I tell the first server block to not take in account `staging.backend.mysite.com`? Is there a way to exclude a specific domain name?

Comment: Are you certain `nginx` is reading your second config? Check it using `nginx -T`

Comment: Yes, nginx is reading my second config. I just checked.

Comment: Check `server_name` for a typo, for example using `.com` instead of `.me`.

Comment: There is no typo in my config I've double checked. (There was a typo in my post but I've corrected).

Comment: I've edited my post to add more informations. Please have a look :)

Comment: Could the application be causing the redirection and losing the sub-sub-domain in the process?

Comment: No, the application is not causing redirection. When I disable `www.backend.mysite.com` server block it works. The site `staging.backend.mysite.com` is working as expected. That mean that indeed the first block overrides the second one.

Comment: have same issue

Comment: did you fix this ? how ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give for included config files same names as domain names, e.g.:

```
aa.domain.com --> aa.domain.com.nginx.conf
bb.domain.com --> bb.domain.com.nginx.conf
```

so nginx will include and catch in natural alphabetic order

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same experience, but eventually when I ran `sudo nginx -T`, it spat out:

```
nginx: [emerg] could not build server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

So, I edited `nginx.conf` and uncommented the relevant line:

```
  # ...
  server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64;
  # ...
```

I picked 64 because that was what was in the file, commented out. Then I restarted and everything worked.

Then I cleared the cache in my browser.